# I need an equation for the Skat Bidding (card game)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, card-games

If you are interested in learning Skat, here are the rules: [Skat Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skat_(card_game))

Before the game starts, there is some bidding to be done. Based on their cards, everyone has a number in their head to which they can agree. Then the bidding starts. One player says 18; the other player says yes or pass. If yes, then the first player says either pass or 20. These are the numbers used:

[image: Skat Bidding Table]

You start with the number 18, 20, 22, ..., 264.

Here is how the numbers are created (a German overview): [Skat Numbers Overview](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skat#/media/Datei:Skatabrechnung.png)

I need your help to create an equation that generates those numbers. Where do I start?

Comment: I don't think there is a nice formula generating these numbers. The list of numbers is too arbitrary for that. But if you are happy with *any* kind of formula, there certainly is a very ugly polynomial of degree 62 doing the job.

Comment: As a dedicated player of Skat the first question that came to my mind was: cui bono?!

Comment: @Tzimmo I would love such an equation. Do you have one?

Comment: No, but [this webpage](https://www.dcode.fr/lagrange-interpolating-polynomial) has a calculator for it. Enter the numbers from 1 to 63 in the first column and the Skat values in the second one.
Also I want to second @MichaelHoppe’s question: What is the use of this formula?

Comment: In real Skat-life numbers more than 48 will rarely occur.